# Group splunk logs by flag value

Tags: logging, distribution, splunk

I have Splunk logs that look like this:

```
2023-08-15 11:51:32.148 INFO  default task-107 com.company.project.log.LogService - createEvent: actionFlag: 1; orderNumber: 2000000; current DateTime: Tue Aug 15 11:51:32 PDT 2023

2023-08-16 11:51:32.148 INFO  default task-109 com.company.project.log.LogService - createEvent: actionFlag: 3; orderNumber: 2000001; current DateTime: Tue Aug 16 11:51:32 PDT 2023

2023-08-16 12:51:32.148 INFO  default task-110 com.company.project.log.LogService - createEvent: actionFlag: 2; orderNumber: 2000005; current DateTime: Tue Aug 16 12:51:32 PDT 2023
```

I need to write a Splunk query to group events by the **actionFlag** value (which can be **1**, **2** or **3**), over any given time period, getting a table/visualization of the nature:

##### Event distribution over the last 30 mins:

| actionFlag = 1 | actionFlag = 2 | actionFlag = 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 12 | 33 |

I've tried extracting a field (actionFlag) but I am not able to understand how to write/select a regex that says the field key = "actionFlag" and the value = "1/2/3" and then group accordingly.

How can I write an appropriate query for this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `rex` command to validate data - just use it to extract fields.  Validation, if necessary, can be done with other commands.

````
``` Extract the actionFlag value ```
| rex "actionFlag:\s+(?<actionFlag>\d)"
``` OPTIONAL - filter out invalid actionFlag values ```
| where actionFlag > 0 AND actionFlag < 4
``` Count the number of events for each actionFlag value ```
| stats count by actionFlag
````